# How do I get the count of values from a geometric sequence that fits in a number

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, enums

I'm not even sure how to explain what I am looking for, but I will give it a try.
The image below shows a geometric sequence in column "LIST"
I'd like to get the count of values of numbers of column "LIST" from for the numbers in column "TEST" in column "NBR"

e.g. The value `116` is a combination of the numbers 64,32,16 and 4, hence the outcome should be 4 (because it takes 4 values to get to 116) in column "NBR"

[image]

Can this be done with a excel formula?

Comment: You mean to ask *how many 1s are there in the binary representation of the decimal number N?* don't you.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, I guess that is what I am looking for :)

Comment: @JvdV I am not sure what you mean

Comment: Nevermind, I think @HighPerformanceMark got you covered.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, sharp mind. I think you can put down an answer using `DEC2BIN()` function which works upto 511 (9-bits) for positive decimals. Something like `=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(DEC2BIN(B2),0,""))` for example.

Comment: @JvdV: no, you go ahead and answer this, you did all the hard work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @HighPerformanceMark, you seem to want to convert a decimal to a binary number to count how many 1s are used. You can use the `DEC2BIN()` function for this which accepts positive decimals upto 511:

```
=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(DEC2BIN(B2),0,""))
```